# Flutter iOS app was breaking while opening

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

My flutter iOS app was breaking after build was completed. Even when i tried to open it was not opening. Throwing a popup Runner quit unexpectedly.

Inside the popup the logs are :

```
-------------------------------------
```

### Translated Report (Full Report Below)

Incident Identifier: 2C07AD8F-BE26-4D29-BE38-770401FE5FF7
CrashReporter Key:   CE986060-29E4-2CF3-43C6-0FCCCE737076
Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1
Process:             Runner [39080]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/23E01CF9-98C7-468E-827C-BAC8AB71AC3B/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.karishye.pujarii
Version:             1.0.7 (62)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [33266]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246 [4235]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [2069]

Date/Time:           2023-08-08 19:04:54.0876 +0530
Launch Time:         2023-08-08 19:04:54.0369 +0530
OS Version:          macOS 13.3.1 (22E772610a)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: @rpath/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay
Referenced from: <726864EC-9B48-3BFA-8091-BE7A33BCA66C> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/23E01CF9-98C7-468E-827C-BAC8AB71AC3B/Runner.app/Runner
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Users/Phanindra/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246/data/Con
(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   ???                                    0x102d249a8 ???
1            0x102dd258c ???
2   dyld                                   0x202f55fd7 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 82
3   dyld                                   0x202f56009 abort_with_payload + 9
4   dyld_sim                               0x10b37a829 abort_with_payload + 26
5   dyld_sim                               0x10b325fea dyld4::halt(char const*) + 375
6   dyld_sim                               0x10b324535 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 3953
7   dyld_sim                               0x10b32325f _dyld_sim_prepare + 577
8   dyld                                   0x202ed8424 dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*) + 1490
9   dyld                                   0x202ed6abc dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 249
10  dyld                                   0x202ed63bd start + 1805

Thread 1:: com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver
0   ???                                 0x7ff7ffd54694 ???

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000000000006  rbx: 0x00000000000000ef  rcx: 0x0000000000000001  rdx: 0x0000000309cca560
rdi: 0x000000204f656e6f  rsi: 0x6850692f736d726f  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000309cca160
r8: 0x0000000309cca160   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00000000000000ef  r11: 0x0000000061399594
r12: 0x00000000000000ef  r13: 0x0000000309cca560  r14: 0x0000000000000001  r15: 0x0000000000000006
rip:        rfl: 0x0000000000000283
tmp0: 0xffffffffffffffff tmp1: 0x0000000102d2497c tmp2: 0x0000000202f55fd7

Binary Images:
0x202ed0000 -        0x202f6bfff dyld (*)  /usr/lib/dyld
0x10b322000 -        0x10b383fff dyld_sim (*) <6fa70830-2b34-3b74-9f1a-ecd763b2e892> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim
0x102cfe000 -        0x102d05fff com.karishye.pujarii (1.0.7) <726864ec-9b48-3bfa-8091-be7a33bca66c> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/23E01CF9-98C7-468E-827C-BAC8AB71AC3B/Runner.app/Runner
0x10bad4000 -        0x10bbf3fff com.apple.CoreTelephony (113) <4202939d-d6e3-3c4a-b5e5-c3869757744d> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x10b5f4000 -        0x10b914fff com.apple.QuartzCore (1.11) <5459b6c0-3bcf-32f7-aa26-0d09d4be0407> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? (*) <00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000> ???

Error Formulating Crash Report:
dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed

EOF

---

### Full Report

{"app_name":"Runner","timestamp":"2023-08-08 19:04:54.00 +0530","app_version":"1.0.7","slice_uuid":"726864ec-9b48-3bfa-8091-be7a33bca66c","build_version":"62","platform":7,"bundleID":"com.karishye.pujarii","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 13.3.1 (22E772610a)","roots_installed":0,"name":"Runner","incident_id":"2C07AD8F-BE26-4D29-BE38-770401FE5FF7"}
{
"uptime" : 25000,
"procRole" : "Foreground",
"version" : 2,
"userID" : 502,
"deployVersion" : 210,
"modelCode" : "MacBookAir10,1",
"coalitionID" : 4235,
"osVersion" : {
"train" : "macOS 13.3.1",
"build" : "22E772610a",
"releaseType" : "User"
},
"captureTime" : "2023-08-08 19:04:54.0876 +0530",
"incident" : "2C07AD8F-BE26-4D29-BE38-770401FE5FF7",
"pid" : 39080,
"translated" : true,
"cpuType" : "X86-64",
"roots_installed" : 0,
"bug_type" : "309",
"procLaunch" : "2023-08-08 19:04:54.0369 +0530",
"procStartAbsTime" : 610543172145,
"procExitAbsTime" : 610544305732,
"procName" : "Runner",
"procPath" : "/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/23E01CF9-98C7-468E-827C-BAC8AB71AC3B/Runner.app/Runner",
"bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"1.0.7","CFBundleVersion":"62","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.karishye.pujarii"},
"storeInfo" : {"deviceIdentifierForVendor":"2118CE2A-638A-5316-A5CB-8B85452353D0","thirdParty":true},
"parentProc" : "launchd_sim",
"parentPid" : 33266,
"coalitionName" : "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246",
"crashReporterKey" : "CE986060-29E4-2CF3-43C6-0FCCCE737076",
"responsiblePid" : 2069,
"responsibleProc" : "SimulatorTrampoline",
"codeSigningID" : "com.karishye.pujarii",
"codeSigningTeamID" : "",
"codeSigningFlags" : 570425861,
"codeSigningValidationCategory" : 10,
"codeSigningTrustLevel" : 0,
"wakeTime" : 5546,
"sleepWakeUUID" : "ED9D402C-B878-40D4-8EBF-9A8DA4E92A84",
"sip" : "enabled",
"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
"termination" : {"code":1,"flags":518,"namespace":"DYLD","indicator":"Library missing","details":["(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)"],"reasons":["Library not loaded: @rpath/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay","Referenced from: <726864EC-9B48-3BFA-8091-BE7A33BCA66C> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/23E01CF9-98C7-468E-827C-BAC8AB71AC3B/Runner.app/Runner","Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/Razorpay.framework/Razorpay' (no such file, no dyld cache), '/Users/Phanindra/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246/data/Con"]},
"extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
"faultingThread" : 0,
"threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":357903,"threadState":{"flavor":"x86_THREAD_STATE","rbp":{"value":0},"r12":{"value":239},"rosetta":{"tmp2":{"value":8639569879},"tmp1":{"value":4342303100},"tmp0":{"value":18446744073709551615}},"rbx":{"value":239},"r8":{"value":13049307488},"r15":{"value":6},"r10":{"value":239},"rdx":{"value":13049308512},"rdi":{"value":138771000943},"r9":{"value":0},"r13":{"value":13049308512},"rflags":{"value":643},"rax":{"value":6},"rsp":{"value":13049307488},"r11":{"value":1631163796},"rcx":{"value":1},"r14":{"value":1},"rsi":{"value":7516623430602289775}},"frames":[{"imageOffset":4342303144,"imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":4343014796,"region":"","imageIndex":5},{"imageOffset":548823,"symbol":"abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal","symbolLocation":82,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":548873,"symbol":"abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":9,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":362537,"symbol":"abort_with_payload","symbolLocation":26,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":16362,"symbol":"dyld4::halt(char const*)","symbolLocation":375,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":9525,"symbol":"dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)","symbolLocation":3953,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":4703,"symbol":"_dyld_sim_prepare","symbolLocation":577,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":33828,"symbol":"dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*)","symbolLocation":1490,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":27324,"symbol":"dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*)","symbolLocation":249,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":25533,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":1805,"imageIndex":0}]},{"id":357904,"name":"com.apple.rosetta.exceptionserver","frames":[{"imageOffset":140703125816980,"imageIndex":5}]}],
"usedImages" : [
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "x86_64",
"base" : 8639021056,
"size" : 638976,
"uuid" : "f22a1143-9732-3e23-a8b7-cbade6bb8301",
"path" : "/usr/lib/dyld",
"name" : "dyld"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "x86_64",
"base" : 4482801664,
"size" : 401408,
"uuid" : "6fa70830-2b34-3b74-9f1a-ecd763b2e892",
"path" : "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/dyld_sim",
"name" : "dyld_sim"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "x86_64",
"base" : 4342145024,
"CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.0.7",
"CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.karishye.pujarii",
"size" : 32768,
"uuid" : "726864ec-9b48-3bfa-8091-be7a33bca66c",
"path" : "/Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/968BC057-3DA1-4C71-AA85-4F416EFE2246/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/23E01CF9-98C7-468E-827C-BAC8AB71AC3B/Runner.app/Runner",
"name" : "Runner",
"CFBundleVersion" : "62"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "x86_64",
"base" : 4490870784,
"CFBundleShortVersionString" : "113",
"CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.CoreTelephony",
"size" : 1179648,
"uuid" : "4202939d-d6e3-3c4a-b5e5-c3869757744d",
"path" : "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony",
"name" : "CoreTelephony",
"CFBundleVersion" : "10226"
},
{
"source" : "P",
"arch" : "x86_64",
"base" : 4485758976,
"CFBundleShortVersionString" : "1.11",
"CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.QuartzCore",
"size" : 3280896,
"uuid" : "5459b6c0-3bcf-32f7-aa26-0d09d4be0407",
"path" : "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore",
"name" : "QuartzCore",
"CFBundleVersion" : "1045.11"
},
{
"size" : 0,
"source" : "A",
"base" : 0,
"uuid" : "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
}
],
"vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=8496K resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=8496K(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=141.6M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=141.6M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nRosetta Arena                     4096K        2 \nRosetta Generic                    976K      241 \nRosetta IndirectBranch              32K        1 \nRosetta JIT                      128.0M        1 \nRosetta Return Stack                20K        2 \nRosetta Thread Context              20K        2 \nStack                             8176K        1 \nStack Guard                       56.0M        1 \nVM_ALLOCATE                         52K        2 \nVM_ALLOCATE (reserved)              20K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\n__DATA                             100K        7 \n__DATA_CONST                       476K        4 \n__DATA_DIRTY                        20K        2 \n__LINKEDIT                        3120K        8 \n__TEXT                            5404K        5 \ndyld private memory               32.0G        5 \nmapped file                        620K        7 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                             32.2G      293 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space    32.2G      293 \n",
"legacyInfo" : {
"threadTriggered" : {

}
},
"logWritingSignature" : "8f87dd38a962b8ef68ee5d83035907f7ed8de10b",
"trialInfo" : {
"rollouts" : [
{
"rolloutId" : "60f8ddccefea4203d95cbeef",
"factorPackIds" : {

```
  },
  "deploymentId" : 240000025
},
{
  "rolloutId" : "62fe74515312cd4599bd3c80",
  "factorPackIds" : {
    "MYRIAD_BOOSTS" : "62fe74805312cd4599bd3c81"
  },
  "deploymentId" : 240000006
}
```

],
"experiments" : [
{
"treatmentId" : "a092db1b-c401-44fa-9c54-518b7d69ca61",
"experimentId" : "64a844035c85000c0f42398a",
"deploymentId" : 400000016
},
{
"treatmentId" : "3a3cf641-8471-4e4e-9ad4-81d0ede970fd",
"experimentId" : "64a84dae90d82611a0bd7d3d",
"deploymentId" : 400000010
}
]
},
"reportNotes" : [
"dyld_process_snapshot_get_shared_cache failed"
]
}

Model: MacBookAir10,1, BootROM 8422.100.650, proc 8:4:4 processors, 16 GB, SMC
Graphics: Apple M1, Apple M1, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2560 x 1600 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR4, Hynix
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_wifi (0x14E4, 0x4378), wl0: Jan 12 2023 05:52:26 version 18.20.383.14.7.8.149 FWID 01-1469d19d
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **Razorpay.framework** is not configured on iOS, thus you must **Rebuild Project** and **clean your build** from **XCode** before proceeding to your vscode/android studio and doing the `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, and `cd ios` commands. futhermore

```
     sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
     pod deintegrate
     pod cache clean --all
     rm Podfile
     sudo gem install cocoapods
     pod install
```

After you've executed these instructions, restart your IDE and relaunch the app.It will start working on ios and never crash.

Comment: are you also getting this info from chatgpt like you now-deleted answer?

Comment: No, there was some missing text for your asked query so that why i Resumitted again.

Comment: @SyedNaseebAli Thank you. It worked for me. I have removed razorpay package and runner the commands you shared it worked.

Comment: its my pleasure to help fellow developers